# With VeeValidate, how can I see if a field has been touched and is valid?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I'm trying to access the validation flags from a computed prop:

```js
computed: {
  isFormValid() {
    let isValid = this.$validator.fields.some(field => {
      console.log(field.flags);
      return field.flags.touched; || field.flags.invalid;
    });
    console.log("isValid", isValid);
    return isValid;
  }
},
```

But this gives an error: `"TypeError: this.$validator.fields.some is not a function"`

So then I figured I would iterate over the `observable`:

```js
let isValid = Array.from(this.$validator.fields).some(field => {
  console.log(field.flags);
  return field.flags.touched; //|| field.flags.invalid;
});
```

Yay! Progress! No more error. But it doesn't recompute when I change the form input values.

So how can I do this?

Comment: I suggest you go throught this topic on official web site - https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/validation-observer.html#validation-observer. I believe it will answer on all your questions

Comment: I did. That’s how I came up with what I did. Problem is that it’s not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [v2 docs show an example](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/flags.html#introduction) that iterates `this.fields`  (instead of `this.$validator.fields`) via [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    isFormDirty() {
      return Object.keys(this.fields).some(key => this.fields[key].dirty);
    }
  },
  //...
}
```

Using that example, your computed prop would be:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    isFormTouchedOrInvalid() {
      return Object.keys(this.fields).some(key => this.fields[key].touched || this.fields[key].invalid);
    }
  },
  //...
}
```

[v2 demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/veevalidate-examples-rc438?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fpages%2FFlags.vue)

In v3, you could [use the `<ValidationProvider>` component](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/validation-provider.html#validation-flags) to easily access the validation flags in the template:

```html
<ValidationProvider rules="required" v-slot="{ touched, invalid }">
  <pre>touched:{{touched}} invalid:{{invalid}}</pre>
  <input type="email" v-model="value">
</ValidationProvider>
```

[v3 demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/veevalidate-30-multi-step-form-example-wv3s9?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FExample.vue)

Comment: Where does `this.fields` come from?

Comment: @Shamoon `this.fields` is a computed prop that [VeeValidate automatically inserts](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/cb8c499/src/mixin.js#L72) in v2. See [more about the mixin](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/00996c7ef832263f5695704487e2bab62a30f27a/docs/api/mixin.md)